# T-SQL - Building Dynamic Query in While Loop

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to build a dynamic query that joins to a variable number of tables. These tables are provided as a parameter `@airflowTablesToSum`, which is split by commas, added to a table and iterated over to create the many joins in `@joinClauses`.

I've run into a problem when concatenating the strings in the while loop, and it is observable with the following code:

```
declare @airflowTablesToSum as varchar(max) = 'FP_1_01RM109CSA_F,FP_1_02RM109ASA_F,FP_1_03RM109DSA_F,FP_1_04RM110SA_F,FP_1_05RM111ASA_F,FP_1_06RM112SA_F,FP_1_07RM108SA_F,FP_1_08MAUTSA_F,FP_1_09SAUTSA_F,FP_1_10SAUTSA_F,FP_1_11MAUTSA_F,FP_1_12RM104SA_F,FP_2_01RM208SA_F,FP_2_02RM207SA_F,FP_2_03RM206SA_F,FP_2_04RM208BSA_F,FP_2_05RM209SA_F,FP_2_06RM209ASA_F,FP_2_07RM205SA_F,FP_2_08RM205ASA_F,FP_2_09RM224SA_F,FP_2_10RM232SA_F,TECHEDFP211RM239SAF,TECHEDFP212RM239ASAF,TECHEDFP213RM204SAF,TECHEDFP214RM213SAF,TECHEDFP215RM215SAF,TECHEDFP216RM219SAF,TECHEDFP217ARM241SAF,TECHEDFP217RM240SAF,TECHEDTU201RM205ESAF,TECHEDTU202RM209BSAF,TECHEDVMA11RM101VSUPFLOW,TECHEDVMA12RM101SSUPFLOW,TECHEDVMA13RM101RSUPFLOW,TECHEDVMA14RM101QBSUPFLOW,TECHEDVMA15RM101PSUPFLOW,TECHEDVMA29RM101ESUPFLOW,TECHEDVMA30RM101KSUPFLOW,TECHEDVMA31RM101JSUPFLOW,TECHEDVMA32RM101SUPFLOW,TU001SAF';

CREATE TABLE #tableNames (id int identity(1,1), tname varchar(max));
insert into #tableNames select value from string_split(@airflowTablesToSum,',');

declare @previousTable varchar(max) = (select tName from #tableNames where id=1);
DELETE FROM #tableNames WHERE tname = @previousTable;

declare @joinClauses varchar(max) = ' ' + @previousTable + ' a ';
declare @tableSum varchar(max) = 'a.[VALUE]';
set @previousTable = 'a';

select * from #tableNames;

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
BEGIN
    declare @currentTable varchar(max) = (select top 1 tname from #tableNames);

    set @joinClauses += ('join ' + @currentTable + ' on cast(' + @currentTable + '.[TIMESTAMP] as smalldatetime) = cast(' + @previousTable + '.[TIMESTAMP] as smalldatetime) ');
    set @tableSum += (' + ' + @currentTable + '.[VALUE]');

    --RAISERROR(@joinClauses,0,1);
    --RAISERROR(@tableSum,0,1);

    set @previousTable = @currentTable;
    DELETE FROM #tableNames WHERE tname = @currentTable;
END
    RAISERROR(@joinClauses,0,1);
    RAISERROR(@tableSum,0,1);

drop TABLE #tableNames;
```

The output messages when executing shows rows being deleted `FROM #tableNames` as expected, **but there is no printing of the variables** `@joinClauses` or `@tableSum` after the `while` loop.

**On the other hand**, if you **comment** those 2 `RAISERROR` lines and **uncomment the pair inside the while loop**, the variables show up for each iteration!

I'm terribly confused and have scoured the depth of the internet for why this is happening. Somebody help me please.

P.S. This will be used in a stored procedure. It's quite long and irrelevant to this issue as I've been able to isolate this as the cause of my bad results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you do not see anything is at the last loop `@currentTable` is null due to the last row has been deleted in the next to last loop. As the `@currentTable` is null, your concatenation for `@joinclauses` and `@tableSum` result in `NULL` values, and won't print.

I would change your code to something like so:

```
declare @airflowTablesToSum as varchar(max) = 'FP_1_01RM109CSA_F,FP_1_02RM109ASA_F,FP_1_03RM109DSA_F,FP_1_04RM110SA_F,FP_1_05RM111ASA_F,FP_1_06RM112SA_F,FP_1_07RM108SA_F,FP_1_08MAUTSA_F,FP_1_09SAUTSA_F,FP_1_10SAUTSA_F,FP_1_11MAUTSA_F,FP_1_12RM104SA_F,FP_2_01RM208SA_F,FP_2_02RM207SA_F,FP_2_03RM206SA_F,FP_2_04RM208BSA_F,FP_2_05RM209SA_F,FP_2_06RM209ASA_F,FP_2_07RM205SA_F,FP_2_08RM205ASA_F,FP_2_09RM224SA_F,FP_2_10RM232SA_F,TECHEDFP211RM239SAF,TECHEDFP212RM239ASAF,TECHEDFP213RM204SAF,TECHEDFP214RM213SAF,TECHEDFP215RM215SAF,TECHEDFP216RM219SAF,TECHEDFP217ARM241SAF,TECHEDFP217RM240SAF,TECHEDTU201RM205ESAF,TECHEDTU202RM209BSAF,TECHEDVMA11RM101VSUPFLOW,TECHEDVMA12RM101SSUPFLOW,TECHEDVMA13RM101RSUPFLOW,TECHEDVMA14RM101QBSUPFLOW,TECHEDVMA15RM101PSUPFLOW,TECHEDVMA29RM101ESUPFLOW,TECHEDVMA30RM101KSUPFLOW,TECHEDVMA31RM101JSUPFLOW,TECHEDVMA32RM101SUPFLOW,TU001SAF';

CREATE TABLE #tableNames (id int identity(1,1), tname varchar(max));
insert into #tableNames select value from string_split(@airflowTablesToSum,',');

declare @previousTable varchar(max) = (select tName from #tableNames where id=1);
DELETE FROM #tableNames WHERE tname = @previousTable;

declare @joinClauses varchar(max) = ' ' + @previousTable + ' a ';
declare @tableSum varchar(max) = 'a.[VALUE]';
set @previousTable = 'a';

select * from #tableNames;

declare @currentTable varchar(max);

SELECT TOP(1) @currentTable =  tname FROM #tableNames

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
BEGIN

    set @joinClauses += ('join ' + @currentTable + ' on cast(' + @currentTable + '.[TIMESTAMP] as smalldatetime) = cast(' + @previousTable + '.[TIMESTAMP] as smalldatetime) ');
    set @tableSum += (' + ' + @currentTable + '.[VALUE]');

    set @previousTable = @currentTable;
    DELETE FROM #tableNames WHERE tname = @currentTable;

    SELECT TOP(1) @currentTable =  tname FROM #tableNames

END
    RAISERROR(@joinClauses,0,1);
    RAISERROR(@tableSum,0,1);

drop TABLE #tableNames;
```

Also, why are are you using `RAISERROR` to in essence `PRINT`?

Anyway, hope this helps!

Niels

Comment: Yes, that is what happened, I just assumed after deleting the first row an dusing another `select`, `@@ROWCOUNT` would adust. Clearly, it doesn't exactly work that way, which is what I still don't understand.
Regardless, that was the issue and I fixed it with your help. Thank you.